Understanding 負けてはいない
I encountered the expression 負けてはいない. I wonder if it is the combination of 負けていない and contrastive は. How does 負けてはいない (meaning "still haven't lost") come to mean "fight equally"? How to use this expression in a sentence?

Just as basic semantics, if Opponent A has fought Opponent B and hasn't lost, that must mean that A and B are relatively evenly matched.

@EiríkrÚtlendi To echo OP’s question though, wouldn’t it also be possible for A to be winning every game?

Since this is a negative sentence, は may or may not be used with a strong contrastive nuance. (cf. Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?)

If there is no contrastive nuance, 負けてはいない is pretty much the same as 負けていない, which means they're fighting equally. It's similar to how "not bad" can mean "rather good" in English.
If there is a contrastive nuance, 負けてはいない means "They at least haven't lost", implying that they are in a very disadvantageous position, but it's not a formal defeat yet.

If the latter meaning is intended, 負けては is pronounced with emphasis when spoken. In a written sentence, however, the intended meaning must be inferred from the context.

Thank you. I wonder how do you understand 決して負けてはいない相手? It either means "opponent who fights equally well with me" or "opponent who I can fight equally with."

@weeab00 The subject of 負ける depends purely on the context. It's ambiguous just as プレゼントを渡す人, 紹介したい人, 好きになった人 and so on are ambiguous in Japanese.

What about this definition for 敵もさる者:〈敵／相手〉も決して負けてはいない者?

@weeab00 The subject of 負ける is the 敵/相手. The phrase is saying the opponent is stronger than one might expect.
