Can someone explain the grammar of 「〜てはない」(て-form verb + はない）
I've been using BunPro to study grammar, and one exercise had the following hint text:
(A)と述べてはないということを表す表現。毎回(A)だということではない。
What caught my attention here was 述べてはない -- the て form of 述べる combined with はない. Can anyone provide info about this grammar structure? I think it's intended to mean "it's not so that A is being commented on / expressed", but I can't seem to find any online resources to describe it.

This is actually a variant of 述べてはいない（述べる＋て＋は＋いる＋ない）. The auxiliary verb いる in the expression ～ている is often shortened to る (especially in casual speech, but sometimes in casual written language as well), for example, ～ている → ～てる and ～ていない → ～てない.

Thank you, that makes sense. I can find much more information now that I know which structure is being used.
e.g.
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/105483/understanding-%e8%b2%a0%e3%81%91%e3%81%a6%e3%81%af%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84
